# MPI anagram code

Tags: c, file, parallel-processing, mpi, anagram

I want to write program that takes a word from user and share anagrams to it in file. I want to do in MPI. But I don't know how I should read file text. This is what I write in this moment.

What should I do? I think about MPI Scatter& Gather but how?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdbool.h>
#include <conio.h>
#include <mpi.h>

bool if_anagram(char *a, char *b)
{

    int dl1 = strlen(a), dl2 = strlen(b);


    if(dl1!=dl2)return false;

    int licz[0x100]={}; 

    for(int i=0;i<dl1;i++)    
        licz[(unsigned char) a[i]]++; 
    for(int i=0;i<dl1;i++)
        licz[(unsigned char) b[i]]--;   
    for(int i=0;i<256;i++)      
        if(licz[i]!=0) 
            return false; 

  return true; 
} 


int main(int argc, char** argv) {

    char a[101], b[101]; 
    FILE *pFile;

    MPI_Init(NULL, NULL);

    int world_rank;
    MPI_Comm_rank(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &world_rank);
    int world_size;
    MPI_Comm_size(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &world_size);

    pFile=fopen("slowa852.txt","r"); 


    printf("Put word to share: ");
        scanf ("%s", a);

    if (pFile != NULL){
    while ( fscanf (pFile,"%s",b) == 1) { 

        if(if_anagram(a,b))
            printf("Word %s is anagram!\n", b);

}
    fclose(pFile); 
  }
  else{
    printf("It cant open file.\n");
  }

    MPI_Finalize();
}
```

Comment: a simple approach is have rank 0 read one word, and have it tested by an available rank or block until a rank becomes available, and then loop until all the file has been read and tested.

Comment: But it will be only on one rank all the time. That the same thing like in serial program or not?So where is parallel in it? You can put some code

Comment: Assuming testing a word takes more time than reading it,  you can feed each rank (but rank 0) a different word, and hence the parallelism.